# Filter on language or country in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I make a Facebook Graph API call so the result only contains posts from a specific country or language?

Comment: Have a look at this question & answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18937540/1515819